# C remove duplicated numbers on a file

Tags: c, file, duplicate-data

I have a binary file with millions of 64 bits unsigned integers on it. What do I need is to remove the duplicated numbers on the file. My idea is to create a hash table on each element will be one number and it's position on the file, this way I can search for duplicated numbers and then remove them based on it's position.

What will be a better way to implement that?

[EDIT]
By remove the duplicated numbers don't mean repleace them with 0, because it's size still being 64 bits. So I believe there is two options: or rewrite the entire file or create a new one with the unique numbers, it means, without the duplicated.

Comment: your question is not clear. Try add more details

Comment: What do you mean by "remove numbers from file"? Are you going to replace them with 0? If you really want to remove them then you will need to re-write the entire file.

Comment: Just one thing to clarify. If you're removing them, why are you keeping their positions? Won't just the first number's position suffice?

Comment: Must you delete all instances of duplicated numbers or must keep first of them?

Comment: @tioPepe, I need to keep the first of them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and Jurlie, more details were added.

Comment: @Fred, I don't get your point. I believe that I need to hold the position of each one to use on fseek releated functions to remove it from my file.

Comment: You can't remove them from the file since files don't work that way. You just need a list of all the unique numbers and then you write them out one by one.

Comment: do you have to keep the values in order? else you can implement a variant of 'sort unique'

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I do agree. So use a hash table isn't the best way to hold all the unique numbers?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong Hash table is fine. You just don't store any value associated with the key. So you use the hash to know whether or not you have already seen the key. Is this faster than loading the entire file, sorting and then handling duplicates when writing? Or do you need to preserve order? And if you need to preserve order than hash table won't be much use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't need to preserve order :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't read the file and evaluate readed numbers. If is first time, you write to a new file, if not, skip this number. For this purpose:

```
do
    read a number
    look for it in a table
    if found then
        skip
    else
        add to table
        write to new file
    endif
while !eof
```

You don't need more information than each number. You don't need its position or hash information.
You may use a malloc-realloc int64 "array", initialized to 0 (means not found) and access to each position with readed number.

Comment: The numbers are 64 bit long, he must have memory for that... which I guess he doesn't. But the idea it's good, I mean it's a start.

Comment: You are suggesting creating an array of size 18,446,744,073,709,551,615? That would take up 2048 petabytes.

Comment: This is because I quoted "array". There are solutions like a pool of arrays, indexed by number mod X and number % X. Come on, more ideas !!!

Comment: In which case you have there *is* a simple hash table. Even if there is no hash function as such, it the same characteristics (fixed size, collision strategy etc).

Answer (score 1):

Sort the file first, then eliminate duplicates when writing to the definitive output.

Edit: 
The best way is [External sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). It assume you already have an algorithm for sorting for a smaller size (use Quick Sort or Merge Sort), and an algorithm for merging.

If your file can fit in ram memory you don't need it.

Comment: What's the best solution to sort the file?

Comment: Yeah, my file fit in ram memory, so no External sorting needed.

Comment: then use Quicksort... Whatever the algorithm, modify the comparison of a and b to ignore one value every time a = b.